# Insert the number zero in INT column

Tags: mysql

I have this table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_cards` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL,`card_number` bigint(20) NOT NULL,`card_cvv` int(2) NOT NULL,`card_expiration` date NOT NULL,`card_company` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

When I try to insert a number that starts with 0 in `card_number` or `card_cvv`, such as **0048**, it seems that mysql by default has removed the first two zeros (recording only the value **48**)

In my case I will have records that start with zeros, is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Save it as a string instead of an int?

Comment: Is 48 different from 0048? If not, then don't store the zeros

Comment: What software product is this for so that I can avoid ever using it? You have a HUGE security gap in your design. Credit card numbers, CVV, and expiration date in plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this it is better to store as a `CHAR(16)`. You know that it's going to be 16 digits long, and this actually stores the values in bytes and not the number. On the other end it is returned as a string, but you actually want a string returned, with zeroes and all. Numbers never add leading zeroes.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_cards` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `card_number` char(16) NOT NULL,
    `card_cvv` char(4) NOT NULL,
    `card_expiration` date NOT NULL,
    `card_company` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I should make a note that if you're actually storing credit card data you should ***never*** do this. Credit card data should not be stored in a database: That's how data breaches happen, and if you think it probably won't happen to you, ***you are wrong***. Use an external site for credit cards or use a third-party API that provides tokens for you to store instead.

Comment: CVV should be a CHAR(4) (e.g. Amex)